# Loop, DNS and Bluebirdjs - promise still works asynchronouse

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I have a little problem with my function that should check if domains with the specific name are available under few top level domains. When I call this function like whois("example434"); it returns undefined instead of array ["example424.org", ..., "example424.com"] . How to modify the function to solve this problem? Where I make mistake?

```css
function whois (name, domains = '*') {
    if ( typeof domains == 'Object' && domains.length > 0 ) {
      var TLD = domains;
    } else {
      var TLD = ['.com','.net','.org','.edu','.gov', '.biz', '.info', '.mobi', '.me', '.tv', '.info', '.io'];
    }

    var available = [];
    Promise.resolve(
      Promise.map(TLD, function(domain) {
        return dns.resolve4(name + domain, (err, addresses) => {
          if (!addresses || addresses.length <= 0 ){
            console.log(name + domain);
            available.push(name + domain);
          }
        });
      })
    ).then(()=>{
      console.log(available);
      return available;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issues are:

1. dns.resolve4 doesn't look like it returns a promise, since it uses nodejs callback pattern, since it doesn't return a promise, Promise.map won't wait for the asynchronous code to complete
2. Why wrap Promise.map in Promise.resolve - makes no sense since Promise.map returns a promise
3. the funciton `whois` never returns a value, hence you get `undefined`
4. `typeof domains` can never be `Object`, did you mean `object` - even that is not a good way to determine if a vlaue is an `Array`

Your title includes the phrase: **promise still works asynchronous** - well, yes, were you expecting something else? Asynchronous code is asynchronous, and nothing will change that

Anyway, your code with the issues annotated:

```
function whois(name, domains = '*') {
    // Issue 4
    if (typeof domains == 'Object' && domains.length > 0) {
        var TLD = domains;
    } else {
        var TLD = ['.com', '.net', '.org', '.edu', '.gov', '.biz', '.info', '.mobi', '.me', '.tv', '.info', '.io'];
    }

    var available = [];
    // Issue 2
    Promise.resolve(
        Promise.map(TLD, function(domain) {
            // Issue 1
            return dns.resolve4(name + domain, (err, addresses) => {
                if (!addresses || addresses.length <= 0) {
                    console.log(name + domain);
                    available.push(name + domain);
                }
                // possible error: if there's an error (err is not falsey) does that really mean the domain is available?
            });
        })
    ).then(() => {
        console.log(available);
        return available;
    });
    // Issue 3
}
```

You'll want to promisify the dns.resolve4 function, `const resolve4 =` in the code below.

I know that bluebirdjs and later nodejs have built in promisify methods however the logic for those would mean an `err` rejects the promise
which you probably do not want.

Also, you want to resolve differently for different **successful** results, so, best to promisify "by hand" as it were

Use `Array.isArray` to determine if TLD is an Array

```
function whois (name, TLD) {
    // if TLD isn't an array, use the default array
    if (!Array.isArray(TLD)) {
        TLD = ['.com','.net','.org','.edu','.gov', '.biz', '.info', '.mobi', '.me', '.tv', '.info', '.io'];
    }

    // prepare the list of full domains to check
    const domains = TLD.map(domain => name + domain);

    const resolve4 = domain => new Promise(resolve => {
        dns.resolve4(domain, (err, addresses) => {
            if (addresses && addresses.length) {
                // domain resolves - so it's not available
                resolve(false);
            }
            // uncomment the next two lines if you want an error to indicate the domain is NOT available
            //else if (err) {
            //    resolve(false);
            } else {
                // it's available
                resolve(domain);
            }
        });
    });

    return Promise.map(domains, resolve4)
    // filter for available domains (i.e. return an array of non-falsey results)
    .then(results => results.filter(domain => domain));
}
```